# How can I view the settings UI and JSON in a split view?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was following a tutorial to change ui setting back to json split settings.

[image]

This is what it looks like after I added these 3 lines,

```
"workbench.settings.editor": "json",
"workbench.settings.openDefaultSettings": true,
"workbench.settings.useSplitJSON": true,
```

But it looks different from what I see in the tutorial, which looks like this

[image]

I think this is way better since it still has a search bar and you can collapse and expand by categories.
Is there a way to change my settings to look like this?

Comment: Have you managed to make it work? I have the same issue

Comment: I haven't unfortunately.

Comment: FYI: this feature has been removed from VS Code entirely :( https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130457

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a built in settings to get that view automatically, however if you open the settings UI interface in an editor, split it, and then in the second editor open the JSON settings, you can split those two editors to achieve the same thing:

[image]

When you update settings via the UI, it reflects those changes in the JSON immediately, similar to the markdown previewer.